# How can this equation be simplified to give $y$?: $x = \frac{(-1)^y ( 5 (-1)^y y - y + (-1)^y - 1))}4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inverse-function, transcendental-equations

I'm trying to convert this equation to the form $y = ...$, but I am stuck. It seems the $y$-root of $(-1)^y$ is not $-1$, but is instead a beast. Here is the overall equation:

$$x = \frac{(-1)^y  ( 5  (-1)^y  y - y + (-1)^y - 1))}4$$

Note: y is an integer, x is an integer.

I could be open to x needing to be a complex number as long as there are solutions where x ∈ { 3+0i, 5+0i, 7+0i, ...} and y ∈ { 5, 8, 11, ...}.

Note: the point is to avoid using separate equations for even vs. odd, but to have one equation that handles both. That's why the first equation has (-1)^n in it; it makes the equation = y when y is even, and (3y+1)/2 when y is odd. However that trick is not as helpful when we only care about every third number instead of every second number.

Context: I'm an old man trying to refresh my math skills by learning about groups and branch groups. I'm not sure how much extra context you want. Trying to build a map between 2n+1 and 3n+2, kind of.

Comment: Er, can you add the scope of the variables $x,y$? Are they integers? Otherwise interpreting non-integer powers of negative numbers can get icky. Also please add some context or this will get closed

Comment: @Arkady done, let me know if more is needed.

Comment: you should separate this function into cases where y is odd and even which will simplify the formula significantly and get rid of the powers of $-1$.

Comment: Consider the cases of $y$ being even or odd separately.

Comment: The point is not to have to consider even and odd separately, but to build that consideration into the equation itself (this was the reason for (-1)^n in the original equation).

Comment: But I think it might be a non-invertible... need to tweak the original not to have any duplicate output (e.g. y=3, x=3; y=5, x=3). Otherwise I guess it's impossible to invert with a single equation.

Comment: When in comes to defining a function, an equation with multiple cases on the right-hand side is just as much a definition as an equation with one case on the right-hand side, and the decision of which to use should depend on which is easier to understand. You can have fun turning a readable equation into a cryptic equation that follows certain restrictions, but in my opinion that's better done as a separate amusement rather than actually trying to do math. Witness this question, where it takes some effort just to convert your equation into a format we can work with.

Comment: It seems that your equation provides a one-to-one mapping between $y\in\{3,5,7,\ldots\}$ and $x\in\{5,8,11,\ldots\}$, but not between $x\in\{3,5,7,\ldots\}$ and $y\in\{5,8,11,\ldots\}$. Did you accidentally swap $x$ and $y$ when you wrote "$x\in\{3+0i,5+0i,7+0i,\ldots\}$ and $y\in\{5,8,11,\ldots\}$"?

Comment: "Trying to build a map between $2n+1$ and $3n+2$, kind of" could go a few different ways. If you really just need that map, make the domain the set of odd integers and the codomain the set of integers congruent to $2$ modulo $3,$ and you can do it with the very simple equation $x=(3y+1)/2.$ Or if you want the domain and codomain to be all the integers, but you only care about what happens to the odd integers in one direction and the integers congruent to $2$ mod $3$ in the other, you want two maps but they don't need to be inverses of each other.

Comment: If you want an invertible map from all integers to all integers then you must not only avoid two inputs mapping to the same output, you must also make sure every possible output is produced. That suggests you really have to deal with three cases, one for integers congruent to $2$ mod $3,$ one for integers congruent to $1$ mod $3$, and one for multiples of $3.$

Comment: If you want to ask a separate question as a follow up, please add a link to it either in an edit or comment on this question so that anyone following the question will be notified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a case decision. Let $y$ be an even integer  then

$$x= \frac{1\cdot   ( 5 \cdot  1\cdot  y - y + 1 - 1))}4=\frac{  4y }4=y$$.

Let $y$ be an odd integer  then

$$x=\frac{-( -5   y - y -1 - 1))}4=\frac{-(-6y-2)}{4}=\frac{6y+2}{4}$$

Solving for y gives $y=\frac{4x-2}{6}=\frac23x-\frac13$. So the function is

$$y=\begin{cases} x, \quad\ \ \ \ \ \ \textrm{if y is an even integer}  \\ \frac23x-\frac13, \textrm{if y is an odd integer}\end{cases}$$

So you calculate both cases, and then you make the decision which one case is right. IMHO it is the easiest approach. I don't see a handy way for non-integers.

Comment: I updated the question to be mote clear; I am trying to find one equation that works for all n ∈ N+. Seems like there ought to be a way to encode if statements into the math itself...

Comment: But I realize this is likely the only solution, as I had an oversight in the original equation. Going to accept this answer and repost with a tweak to the equation.

Comment: O.K. I'm sure you'll get an appropiate answer for your new question.

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer to the question implied by the comment, "Seems like there ought to be a way to encode if statements into the math itself."

Indeed there is a way to encode if statements. First we have to craft a function whose value depends on whether the condition of the "if" is true. Ideally the function will produce just two values, $1$ if the condition is true and $0$ if it is false; then the function is called an *indicator function* (or sometimes a *characteristic function*, but that term has other meanings in some contexts).

For example, for "$n$ is odd," we want a function $I_\text{odd}$ (where the $I$ stands for "indicator") with the domain of integers defined by
$$
I_\text{odd}(n) =
 \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if $n$ is odd,}\\ 0 & \text{if $n$ is even,} \end{cases}
$$
which can be implemented by
$$
I_\text{odd}(n) = n - 2 \left\lfloor \frac n2\right\rfloor.
$$

For "$n \equiv 2 \pmod5$" (which is another way of saying that $n=5t+2$ for some integer $t$) we can define a function $I_{(2\bmod5)}$ over integers such that
$$
I_{(2\bmod5)}(n) = \left\lfloor \cos^2\left(\frac{n-2}5 \pi\right) \right\rfloor
$$
which works because $\frac{n-2}5 \pi$ is an exact integer multiple of $\pi$ if and only if $n-2$ is divisible by $5,$ and the only time when $\cos^2(x)=1$ is when $x$ is an exact integer multiple of $\pi$; for all other $x,$ $0\leq \cos^2(x) < 1.$

More generally for "$n \equiv k \pmod m$" we can define a function $I_{(k\bmod m)}$ over integers by
$$
I_{(k\bmod m)}(n) = \left\lfloor \cos^2\left(\frac{n-k}m \pi\right) \right\rfloor.
$$

Now let's suppose that for some particular function $f$ that we want to define, we have defined sets $A,$ $B,$ and $C$ that are a partition of the integers
(that is, $A,$ $B,$ and $C$ are pairwise disjoint and $A\cup B\cup C = \mathbb Z$)
so that we can define $f$ using "if" conditions as follows:

$$
f(n) = \begin{cases}
 f_A(n) & \text{if $n \in A$,}\\
 f_B(n) & \text{if $n \in B$,}\\
 f_C(n) & \text{if $n \in C$.}\end{cases} \tag1
$$

Then if we can construct indicator functions $I_A,$ $I_B,$ and $I_C$ such that
$I_A(n) = 1$ if $n\in A,$ $I_A(n)=0$ otherwise,
and similarly for $I_B$ and $I_C,$ we can define $f$ like this:

$$
f(n) = I_A(n) f_A(n) + I_B(n) f_B(n) + I_C(n) f_C(n).
$$

Simple, right? The difficulty only comes when you try to write out this function's formula in detail (because you have to figure out the three indicator functions, which could get pretty weird) and when someone else tries to figure out what you've written.
It will usually be a lot harder to read and to work with than something that looks like Equation $(1)$.